# Xamarin Forms WatchOS main iOS app couldn’t be found

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017, watchkit, apple-watch

I am trying to create a watchOS app in an existing Xamarin Forms application in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows. I have followed all the steps listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/watchos/get-started/project-references?tabs=macos). I have also added watchOS app project reference to the main iOS app by selecting add reference option of the references node of the main iOS app. Solution also builds successfully but when I try to launch watchOS app in watch simulator, it instantly throws the below error without even launching the simulator.

Error:
Main iOS app couldn't be found, please make sure you've created an iOS app and it is referencing

Please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have add the watchOS app reference in a wrong place.

You should add the reference in **xxx.iOS** projecct instead of **xxx**(xamarin.forms project).

Let me show a screenshot for you:

[image: reference]

**Update:**

Steps:

1. I create a new `MobileApp(Xamarin.forms)` project(platform `iOS`).
2. Right click on the solution -->add --> new project -->Apple Watch -->watchOS app-->ok.
3. Right click on the `xxx.iOS project` --> add---> reference --> check `XXX.watchOSApp`

   [image: refer]
4. Right click on the **xxx.WatchOSApp** --> `Set as Setup Project`.
5. (Clean and rebuild) Run on the `appleWatch` simulator.

Comment: Thank you Jack for your response. I have already mentioned that watchOS app reference is added to the main iOS app as you mentioned please. One more thing in your screenshot, why there is yellow exclamation mark against the reference? How did you add the reference? Can you please tell me the way you added the reference please?

Comment: @TishaAnand I added my steps, please check.

Comment: I have carried same steps as mentioned by you but with no success. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: @TishaAnand Did you use a new project? Can you upload your project so that I can check it for you.

Comment: Watch kit app is added to an existing project. I am not able to upload the solution as it is a client project

Comment: @TishaAnand Can you try add it in a new project and check if it works? If it works, it may caused some setting of the existing project. If not, maybe other reasons.

Comment: @TishaAnand Can you upload your project with new project?

Comment: I can do it from my home pls. It will take some hours

Comment: No problem. I will check it once you upload it.